# Replacing/Updating record in database without null values?

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the .AddOrUpdate-method for taking a model(Entity) and updating the existing record in my database. The problem is that I don't want the null values coming from the model to overwrite the existing values in the record. It's suppose to only overwrite the values that differ from the existing ones except the null-values coming form the model. What method/technique should I use for this. I dont wanna retrieve the record from the db and replace the null-values in the new object before putting it back into the db in order to do this.

Alos I don't wanna be forced to update single values in the record since several values in the model may be changed. Therefore I'm sending the entire object instead of sending values as parameters to the method executing the database commands.

Thanks alot. I hope my description makes some sence... Otherwise I'll try to elaborate :)

Comment: Is this the model coming from your View? If so, why it is having null values? One solution would be to create a ViewModel with only required data/properties for the view.

Comment: I don't think this would be the solution since the view contains a form for changing a User Profile and the textboxes that are left empty should not change the values of the object. This is why the model returned from the view is returning null values since not all inputs are filled with values necessarily... For example one wants to change the address but leave everything else empty. Thanks for the answer though!